# What is the meaning of the function na() in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I can't find nor understand the funcion `na()` in pinescript. In the example below, the script prints a Heikin Ashi OHLC bars for a specific custom timeframe

```js
//@version=4
strategy("[⚡TC⚡] Heikin Ashi Timeframes", overlay=false)

higherRes =input(title="Time 1", type=input.string, defval="90")

is_newbar(res) => 
    t = time(res) 
    not na(t) and (na(t[1]) or t > t[1])

o = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherRes, open)
h = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherRes, high) 
l = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherRes, low)
c = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherRes, close)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the **documentation**, you will find section "[Preventing `na` values, functions `na` and `nz`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#preventing-na-values-functions-na-and-nz)" describing its purpose:

> In addition, there is a simple function with one argument that returns a logical result called `na`. This function makes it possible to check if the argument is `na` or not. Check it out [here](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_na).

The link is a description of the function:

> **`na`**
>
> Test value if it's a NaN.
>
> ```
> na(x) → bool
> ```
>
> ```
> na(x) → series[bool]
> ```
>
> *Returns*
>
> true if x is not a valid number (x is NaN), otherwise false.
>
> *See also*
>
> [`na`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_na) [`fixnan`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_fixnan) [`nz`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_nz)